# Type a class so that all methods match enum

Tags: typescript

I have a `Pages` enum here and I'd like to type the class methods, so that they match the enum. How can I achieve this?

```
enum Pages {
  accessLogout = 'access.logout',
  accessLogin = 'access.login'
}

interface PageType {
}

type Example = {
  [x in Pages]: PageType
}

class PagesIndex implements Example {
  [Pages.accessLogout] = {
  }
  [Pages.accessLogin] = {
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "type the class methods"

Answer (score 0):

Hardly you can achieve it with a class. But you can create an object instead, maybe it will be enough:

```js
const pagesIndex: Example = {
  [Pages.accessLogout]: {},
  [Pages.accessLogin]: {}
};
```